# How can I change the Navbar button color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, navbar

I wanted to custom my navbar with different colors, but I could only manage o change the background color successfully. Whenever I try to change other attributes, it simply won't work - it will simply use the default dark grey.

I'm goal is to use:

- background color : #97caca
- :active background color : #6dafad
- default color : #fff
- :active and hoover color : #d4e1e3

https://jsfiddle.net/zfv61Lmu/7/

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  height: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.nav .active {
  background: #6dafad!important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: #6dafad;
}

.affix {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  transition: padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #d1e6c5; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">PT</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">FR</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light" style="background-color: #97CACA; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#"><img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="https://ibb.co/ejwDtS" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Bebés e Crianças</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Adultos e Séniores</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Empresas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also, how can I cut the height by half on the fist navbar? It is too thick. I wanted it to be thinner thus it will only be used to change the language. (also, why isn't the glyphicon align?).

Comment: I don't see you written the `:hover` psuedo class in you css!

Comment: no, not yet, I was trying to put the :active working first, then I'd do the :hover

Comment: `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a{
  background-color: #6dafad;
}` - This will change the color of `active`. Please add this and update your question.

Comment: @CatarinaVilhenaCabrita, make sure your CSS selectors have the same or higher specificity than the Bootstrap CSS selectors. If your CSS selectors have the same specificity, make sure your CSS is included after the Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a class to the top navbar: navbar-top.
I've also used child selector (>).
Try to avoid using !important in css.

```css
body {
    height:100%;
    padding-top:50px;
}

section {
  height:calc(90% - 50px);
}


 
.affix {
  padding:0px;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.5s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.5s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.5s linear;  
}


.navbar.navbar-top {
  background: #d1e6c5;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar.navbar-top li a:link,
.navbar.navbar-top li a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}


.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-light { 
  background-color: #97CACA;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 max-height: 50px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li.active > a {
   background: #6dafad;
   color: #d4e1e3;
 }
 
 .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a:hover {
    color: #d4e1e3;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
  <title>navbar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--/ INICIO cabeçalho <-->
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-top">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
     <li>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
          </li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">PT</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">FR</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#"><img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
   <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Bebés e Crianças</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Adultos e Séniores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Empresas</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!--/ FIM cabeçalho <-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the other post.
Try this one:

I have added a class to the top navbar: navbar-top. I've also used child selector (>). Try to avoid using !important in css.

```css
body {
    height:100%;
    padding-top:50px;
}

section {
  height:calc(90% - 50px);
}


 
.affix {
  padding:0px;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.5s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.5s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.5s linear;  
}


.navbar.navbar-top {
  background: #d1e6c5;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar.navbar-top li a:link,
.navbar.navbar-top li a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}


.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-light { 
  background-color: #97CACA;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 max-height: 50px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li.active > a {
   background: #6dafad;
   color: #d4e1e3;
 }
 
 .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a:hover {
    color: #d4e1e3;
 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt">
    <head>
      <title>navbar</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!--/ INICIO cabeçalho <-->
    <div id="wrap">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-top">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
         <li>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
              </li>
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
         <li><a href="#">PT</a></li>
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
         <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
         <li><a href="#">FR</a></li>
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
         <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#"><img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
       </div>
       <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bebés e Crianças</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adultos e Séniores</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Empresas</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ FIM cabeçalho <-->
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to change the colors with:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a{ 
    background-color: #6dafad;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius:
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}
```